# cucumber test gives error - Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError

Tags: tinymce, cucumber, capybara

i have a tinymca's iframe inside my page and i want to fill_in that tinymca editor with the cucumber test. whenever i run my test it gives me error that jQuery not defined

in my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'capybara'
gem 'capybara-mechanize', :git => 'git://github.com/JerryWho/capybara-mechanize.git',      :branch => 'relative-redirects'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'pry'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

here is my scenario

```
Scenario: admin puts all the valid and require data  
    when Job added with all the valid and require data
    Then I should see the success message.
```

and here is the steps for that test

```
Given(/^I am logged in as a company admin$/) do
   visit('/')
   fill_in "log", :with => "admin@email.com"
   fill_in "pwd", :with => "password"
   click_button "submit"
end

When(/^Job added with all the valid and require data$/) do
   visit('/site/admin/posts/add/')
   within_frame 'questiontextarea_ifr' do
       page.execute_script("jQuery(tinymce.editors[0].setContent('my content hersssssssssse'))")
   end
   click_button "Save"
end

Then(/^I should see the success message\.$/) do
   page.should have_content('Success Your post has been successfully added.')   
end
```

but it gives me error `jQuery is not defined (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because "jQuery is not defined", as the message suggested.

Please try call without jQuery, but with native [TinyMCE API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent):

```
page.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('my content hersssssssssse')")
```

Further reading: [Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/#set-content) in pure Ruby (not Capybara)